# Check if array contain specific string

Tags: xcode, arrays, nsarray, contains

I am saving different codes in a array and now want to check if one code is in the array.

I searched a bit around but nothing working...

**Here you see how my array looks:**

```
2013-04-28 12:43:23.877 myApp[9422:907] PushArray: (
    {
    code = 123;
    titel = "Test 01";
},
    {
    code = 456;
    titel = "Test 02";
},
    {
    code = 789;
    titel = "Test 03";
}
)
```

**I tried this to check:**

```
NSString *code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"];;

if ([PushArray containsObject:code]) {
    NSLog(@"Code true!");
}else {
    NSLog(@"Code false!");
}
```

But every time I get "**Code false!**" back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects in your array are actually NSDictionary objects. So to compare numbers, let's enumerate on the array and do the compare on the value from that dictionary object:

```
NSNumber * code = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 123];
for(NSDictionary * anEntry in pushArray)
{
    NSNumber * numberFromEntry = [anEntry objectForKey: @"code"];
    if([code isEqualToNumber: numberFromEntry])
        NSLog( @"code true!");
}
```

Also, notice that I changed the name of your array from "`PushArray`" to "`pushArray`".  Standard Objective-C convention is to use lowercase letters for variables & objects and use uppercase for naming classes.

(the original version of my answer -- which I quickly caught and edited -- was to compare the strings; but I'm guessing those code values in the dictionary objects are actually numbers and not strings)

Comment: oh damn I forgot that there is an dict inside the array ://
Thanks a lot, u code works!

Comment: Is there a way to get a NSString with "code true" or "code false" as return from the "for"?

Comment: instead of "`NSLog( @"code true!");`", do a "`return @"code true";`" (assuming the return type of your function is a NSString)

Comment: perfect and is there also a possibility to delete all entries in the dictionary that contain the code 
Like `if([code isEqualToNumber: numberFromEntry])
        DELETE ENTRY;`
Thanks a lot for u help! :)

Comment: only if it's a mutable dictionary or a mutable array that we're working with.

Comment: those mutable objects have delete methods, like [NSMutableArray removeObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObject:)

Comment: I tried the following, but the App crashed...

`for(NSMutableDictionary * pushDict in array) {
        NSString * codeFromDict = [pushDict objectForKey: @"code"];
        if([code isEqualToString: codeFromDict]){
            [pushDict removeObjectsForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"code", @"title", nil]];
        }
    }`

Comment: [Okay here is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263487/remove-specific-objects-from-nsmutabledictionary)