# Remove specific objects from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: xcode, arrays, nsmutabledictionary

I am saving different codes in a NSMutableDictionary and checking later if a specific code is in the dict.

No I want to remove the entry which contain the code.

**Here you see how my array with the dict looks:**

```
2013-04-28 12:43:23.877 myApp[9422:907] pushArray: (
    {
    code = 123;
    titel = "Test 01";
},
    {
    code = 456;
    titel = "Test 02";
},
    {
    code = 789;
    titel = "Test 03";
}
)
```

**Here you see how I search for the code:**

```
for(NSMutableDictionary * pushDict in pushArray) {
    NSString * codeFromDict = [pushDict objectForKey: @"code"];
    if([code_I_search isEqualToString: codeFromDict]){
        // This is called if the code is found
    }
}
```

This is all working fine, but now I don't now how to remove the entry...

**The result should be:**

If I search for code `789` and say "remove" this would be removed:

```
{
code = 789;
titel = "Test 03";
}
```

I tried `[pushDict removeAllObjects];` but thats not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove that whole entry, right?

If so, then make your "`pushArray`" a `NSMutableArray` and then you can remove the offending dictionary entries via:

```
for(NSDictionary * pushDict in pushArray) {
    NSString * codeFromDict = [pushDict objectForKey: @"code"];
    if([code_I_search isEqualToString: codeFromDict]){
        [pushArray removeObject: pushDict];
    }
}
```

The way you're doing it up there, you're removing all objects from the pushDict, but not the actual pushDict object from the (immutable) array.